Implementing Role-Based Authorization in Next.js 14 with Supabase: Efficient Role Storage and Verification
I understand how to handle authentication with Supabase, but when it comes to implementing authorization, where I want to differentiate functionality based on roles, would it be best to create a separate table to store roles and then verify these roles in a Middleware.ts file? The environment is Next.js 14 with Supabase as the BaaS, and OAuth will also be handled using Supabase.
I’m considering the following approach: After logging in with OAuth, I would use the userID as a key to fetch the roles, store them in the JWT, and then return the JWT to the user. The roles would then be checked in the middleware to control access.

Your approach looks good, always remember to implement RBAC in the front and also in the backend endpoints.
Depending on your front-end architecture is also a very good idea to implement an endpoint that checks which routes can be accessed by the logged-in user, this allows you to monitor and prevent users accessing views/screens that they are not allowed to.
Good luck!
